# Regular expression to detect /en/ or /nl/ in start of string

Tags: php, regex

Let whether a string starts with /en/ or /nl/ or /ab/ in other words:

/ followed by two letters and ended by /

There could be something in the end of string but that doesn't mind.

Examples:

```
/nl/ -> match
/marketing/ -> no match
/marketing.html -> no match
/12/ -> no match
```

I've tried: ^/[a-z]/$ but i think i'm not on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
#^/(en|nl|ab)/#
```

OR to match any 2 letters at start:

```
#^/[a-zA-Z]{2}/#
```

- PHP allows you to use alternate regex delimiter like `#`
- `[a-zA-Z]` will match letters a-z OR A-Z
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` will match exactly 2 letters (a-z OR A-Z)
- `/[a-zA-Z]{2}/` will match exactly 2 letters (a-z OR A-Z) preceded and followed by `/`

Comment: Any particular reason you've encapsulated your regexes with octothorpes?

Comment: No particular reason, it could be `~^/[a-zA-Z]{2}/~` also. Idea was to use anything other that `/`

Comment: Hmm.  `#` and `/` seem equally arbitrary to me.  Since the code is already marked as code in markdown, why have anything at all?  Or if anything, since the question is tagged [tag:php], wouldn't quotes make more sense?

Comment: Yes true in PHP regex is always used in quotes like `'#^/[a-zA-Z]{2}/#'`

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your expression:

- `[a-z]` only matches ONE of the characters in the character set `[a-z]`
- `$` matches end of string, and if it's the first part of the uri, the seconds `/` is probably not at the end of the string.
- if you use `/` as delimiters, any `/` in the regular expression must be escaped, by using `\/` (see my example below).

Use:

```
^\/([a-z]+)\/
```

Or if you only want to get it it's two characters:

```
^\/([a-z]{2})\/
```

Example:

```
$matchings = array();

$uri = '/en/user/131';
if (preg_match('/^\/([a-z]+)\//', $uri, $matchings))
{
    echo "Language: " . $matchings[1];
}
```

Prints:

```
Language: en
```